# Listing down the permutations subjected to the condition of an inequality

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $\sigma$ :{1,2,3,4,5} $\to$ {1,2,3,4,5} be a permutation such that:
$$\sigma^{-1}(j) \leq \sigma(j) ; \forall j=1,2,..,5 $$
Then ,which of the following are correct?

a) $\sigma o \sigma (j)= j; \forall j$

b) $\sigma^{-1}(j)=\sigma(j);\forall j)$

c) The set {k : $\sigma$ (k)=k} has an odd number of elements.

d) The set {k : $\sigma$ (k) $\neq$ k} has an even number of elements.

I understood here that under the given condition identify permutation definitely holds. So, options a) and b) must be true. But I am unable to list down any other permutation which satisfies the condition given to check the validity of the last 2 options. Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

As already the example of identity shows, c) is false *in general*.

According to a), $\sigma$ is an involution, hence partitions $\{\,k:\sigma(k)\ne k\,\}$ into pairs $\{x,\sigma(x)\}$. We conclude that $\{\,k:\sigma(k)\ne k\,\}$ has even cardinality, d) is correct.
This also shows that c) is in fact *always* false.